# Как вывести объект с точкой $model->user.name_user GridView::widget yii2

Tags: yii2, gridview

Пытаюсь организовать вывод данных в одном столбце в  GridView::widget, но так как у я использовал $query->joinWith(['user']); у меня не получается вывести объект  $model->user.name_user  так как php воспринимает  точку как  конкатенации.
Как правильно организовать данный вывод объекта $model->user.name_user?

```
[
        'attribute' => 'price',
        'label' => 'price',
        'value' => function($model) { 

            return $model->user.name_user  . " " . $model->amount ;},
   ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Для получения связанного объекта нужно использовать `->`

```
$model->user->name_user
```

Comment: Так не работает Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Через точку в php обращение к объекту нет и никогда не будет. Сделайте var_dump($model);